# Merging DataFrames based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization

I'm trying to merge two data frames based on one data frames values being within the range of values from another data frame. My data looks like this

```
headingdf = pd.DataFrame({'heading':['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                         'anomaly_start':[4, 17, 40, 61, 64],
                         'anomaly_end':[5, 19, 41, 65, 67]})
  heading  anomaly_start  anomaly_end
0       A              4            5
1       B             17           19
2       B             40           41
3       C             61           65

stockdf = pd.DataFrame({'ticker':['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'AMZN'],
                         'anomaly_start':[4,18,18, 69]})
ticker  anomaly_start
0   AAPL              4
1   AAPL             18
2   AMZN             18
3   AMZN             69
```

I want to return a data frame that merges the data frames based on the start and end times of the anomalies being close. `If stockdf['anomaly_start'] in range(headingdf['anomaly_start], heading['anomaly_end']+5)` So it would return something like this

```
  heading ticker anomaly_ticker_start anomaly_heading_start  \
0       A   AAPL                    4                     4   
1       B   AAPL                   18                    17   
2       B   AMZN                   18                    17   
3       C   AMZN                   69                    61   
4       D   AMZN                   69                    64   

  anomaly_heading_end  
0                   5  
1                  19  
2                  19  
3                  65  
4                  67
```

So far the code below returns what I need but it does not scale well and runs incredibly slow over my dataset of 25000 heading observations and 16000 stock observations

```
matched_anomalys = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['heading',
                                          'ticker',
                                          'anomaly_ticker_start',
                                          'anomaly_heading_start',
                                          'anomaly_heading_end'])
for _, hrow in headingdf.iterrows():
    for _, srow in stockdf.iterrows():
        if int(srow['anomaly_start']) in range(int(hrow['anomaly_start']),int(hrow['anomaly_end'])+5):
            matched_anomalys = matched_anomalys.append({'heading':hrow['heading'],
                                          'ticker':srow['ticker'],
                                          'anomaly_ticker_start':srow['anomaly_start'],
                                         'anomaly_heading_start':hrow['anomaly_start'],
                                          'anomaly_heading_end':hrow['anomaly_end']}, ignore_index=True)
```

What can I do to optimize this/make it run more efficiently? I couldn't find any examples of merging pandas dataframes based on a condition

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [`pd.merge_asof(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)? It has an example with tickers. Pay attention to `tolerance` parameter there.

To preserve `anomaly_heading` from `headingsdf` we needed to duplicate it.

```
>>> headingdf["anomaly_heading_start"] = headingdf["anomaly_start"]
>>> pd.merge_asof(stockdf, headingdf, on="anomaly_start")
  ticker_x  anomaly_start ticker_y  anomaly_end  anomaly_heading_start
0     AAPL              4        A            5                      4
1     AMZN             18        B           19                     17
2     AMZN             70        C           65                     61
```

Comment: This would be 1 to 1 matching though right? Sometimes headings have multiple matches as well as vice versa. I've updated my data to reflect this

Comment: @EthanSurdykowski that is a good question. Don't know at the moment.